# What iElement represents in link function in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="model in ModelList">
  <td>
      <div my-directive name="Sub_{{$index}}">
      </div>
  </td>               
</tr>
```

Javascript Snippet:

```
.directive("myDirective", function(){

    return function (scope, iElement, attrs) {

                    //current name:  Sub_{{$index}}
                    console.log("current name:  " + iElement.attr("name"));

                    //outerHTML: "<div my-directive="" name="Sub_2"></div>"
                    console.dir(iElement);

           };
});
```

My question is, why it return unresolved name( ***Sub_{{$index}}*** ) when i call ***iElement.attr("name")***, and return resolved html( ***name="Sub_2"*** ) when i call ***console.dir(iElement)***?

Here are outputs:

1.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GxKz.png)
2.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9zWI.png)

What exactly is **iElement** behind the scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What exactly is iElement behind the scene?

It is the raw DOM element of the directive wrapped in a `jqLite` wrapper. For more information on `jqLite` and its methods see the [AngularJS angular.element API Reference -- jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angular-s-jqlite)

> why it return unresolved name( `Sub_{{$index}}` ) when i call `iElement.attr("name")`

You are seeing the raw attribute before the directive compiler applies `$interpolate` to it.

> and return resolved html( `name="Sub_2"` ) when i call `console.dir(iElement)`?

When you use `console.dir(iElement)` the console shows the **object reference** at its **present value** (not past value) which is after the attribute has been interpolated.

**More information**

For more information on the `scope` methods such as [$eval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval), [$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch), etc. see the [AngularJS $rootScope.scope API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope).

For more information on the `attrs` methods such as [$observe](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes#$observe), the [AngularJS $compile Directive Attributes API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes).

Comment: So you mean **console.dir** is asynchronous, right? Another question, which make me more confused,  is what is the difference between **iElement** ( described as ***instance element*** in AngularJS document )  in ***link function*** and **tElement** (described as ***templated element*** in AngularJS document) in ***compile function***? It seems that both **iElement** and **tElement** are unresolved(i mean compiler has not applied $interpolate to them yet).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is just a timing issue related to when those bindings get resolved. Instead of trying to get the attribute off the element, have you tried just accessing it from the **attrs** object that is passed into your link function?

```
attrs.name
```

You get the added benefit of angular normalizing the attribute names for you. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes

If you are accessing it just as an attribute, you may need to observe it for changes if you need to account for values that could change after the initial render.

```
scope.$observe(attrs, "name", function(newVal) {
   //do something with the new value
});
```